# CSS styling using querySelectorAll('link') is not the same in child window from parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fix a bug where the parent grabs all the css styling from the parent window using the following code

```
const copiedFromParentStyling = document.createElement('link');
    document.querySelectorAll('link').forEach(htmlElement => {
      if (htmlElement.rel === 'stylesheet') {
        const absoluteUrl = new URL(htmlElement.href).href;
        copiedFromParentStyling .rel = 'stylesheet';
        copiedFromParentStyling .href = absoluteUrl;
      }
    });
```

This information is pass to the routed child window. The expected css results should be the same as the parent but the child window styling is not correct. In the Chrome Inspect tool, some of the css properties shows "Invalid Property Value".

There are css properties with view width like width : 2vw; but the copied css does not work and will not take the 2vw.

Is this because the querySelectorAll returns a static collection? I read that getElementsByClassName() return live styling collection but this method looks to specified by class name. I am hoping to copy everything from the parent and pass to the child. What are other alternative methods to used. Strange, in the child window, The chrome inspect tool will not let me override/re-enter properties. Some of the entire properties that works on parent, shows as crossed out and I can't re-add the properties in the child inspect panel.

Thanks in advance.